# Cutoff body content from Guzzle response

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using Guzzle to login to a page, and then parse the DOM for download links. 
However, I won't receive the full DOM after login. The HTML with the download links is just about to start in the DOM string and then cuts off.

Does someone have any idea what could be the cause of this?

The page is behind login and not public accessible.

Note: I cannot share the URLs nor Login data, so replicating the issue is most likely impossible.

This is the end of the DOM

```
</SCRIPT>
  <TABLE   ALIGN=LEFT CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1 style='WIDTH:99%;max-width:1000px;'>
```

(after that there is nothing, but should be, its just not in the response somehow)

PHP: 7.1.26

Guzzle: 6.3.3

Some code, if its helpful:

```
$response = self::$client->get(self::getConfig()['baseurl'] . '/' . parse_url($mainScreenUri)['path'], [
                'query'   => $query_params,
                'sink'    => date('Y.m.d_H-i-s') . '_sink_.txt',
                'debug'   => TRUE,
                'headers' => [
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept'     => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                    'Host'       => 'snip',
                ]
            ]
        );

        $x = $response->getBody()->__toString();
        file_put_contents(date('Y.m.d_H-i-s') . '.txt', $x);
```

Both files created by this are cut and do not show the full body.

Response debug:

```
* Found bundle for host snip: 0x5625c0ab6100 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host snip
* Connected to snip port 443 (#0)
> GET snip HTTP/1.1
Host: snip
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Cookie: snip

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 12:55:56 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.26
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host snip left intact
```

*edit*
Using streams to only fetch few bytes at a time I have the same problem.

```
/** @var \GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise $promise */
        $promise = self::$client->getAsync(self::getConfig()['baseurl'] . '/' . parse_url($mainScreenUri)['path'], [
                'query'           => $query_params,
                'sink'            => 'snip' . date('Y.m.d_H-i-s') . '_sink_.txt',
                'debug'           => $resource,
                'stream'          => TRUE,
                'headers'         => [
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept'     => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                    'Host'       => 'snip',
                    //                    'Referer'    => 'snip/popup.php?user=' . self::getConfig()['username'] . '&pwi=' . $pwi . '&pwh=' . $hpw,
                ],
                'allow_redirects' => [
                    'max' => 50,
                ]
            ]
        );

        /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $response */
        $response = $promise->wait();

        /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream $body */
        $body = $response->getBody();

        $dataRead = "";
        while (!$body->eof()) {
            $data     = $body->read(1024);
            $dataRead .= $data;
        }
```

`$dataRead` is cutoff like everything else.

Comment: If I understand you correct  you want to load page to some specific place and stop loading. I think you need read from http socket.

Comment: No, I don't want to partially load the page. It must be loaded completely, so I can get the full body. A partial body does not help me and is unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was a parameter which was broken and the server decided to give back broken HTML instead of a error message or nothing at all.